# Ubuntu get package source from universe repository, but the correct source is in main repository

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude, package-management, repository

I want to get source of `thinkfinger' package,

```
sudo apt-get source thinkfinger
```

But, it reports 403 error, and I found that it get the source from xxxx/pool/universe/t/thinkfinger/, but the correct location is in xxxx/pool/main/t/thinkfinger/.

So, is there any option for apt-get to specify which repository should it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not happen at all just by design of APT, and so there is no method of specifying *repository* (there are methods of specifying *release*, but that is not the case).

Probably your local package cache got corrupted somehow, or just is out of date. Try doing `sudo aptitude update`.

Comment: Thanks. 

I have the repository mirrored to my portable disk, the problem is about symlink. In universe/ repository, the fingerprint-x.x-orig.tar.gz is linked to main/, and it is Apache forbid to serve the symlink.

Comment: You should have noted that in your question, because it is impossible to guess that and, as a consequence, impossible to answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In the origial Ubuntu repository thinkfinger isn't in main but in universe.

If you access the disc locally use file:// URLs instead of http:// URLs in /etc/apt/sources.list. If you need to access it via http enable symlink following for your repository directories.